# VBA Security Notices - "Data connections have been blocked"

Tags: excel, vba, security, connection, blocked

I'm trying to determine the cause for a "Microsoft Excel Security Notice" associated with a .xlam file.  In particular, I'm curious if there are certain properties or methods in the VBA code that result in this type of security notice?  We have another .xlam that we install as an add-in, and it has never resulted in a similar notice, thus leading me to believe there is a certain property or method being used that is causing the issue.  I have commented out a number of lines to see if I can isolate the offender myself, but no luck thus far.

Examples of code commented out;

```
pathToCSV = ActiveWorkbook.Path
HostName = ActiveWorkbook.Name
Set Globe = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set place = Globe.GetFolder(pathToCSV)
Set Destination = Application.Workbooks.Add
```

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

[image: Data connections have been blocked]

Comment: In the add-in project, is `ThisWorkbook.Connections.Count` zero?

Comment: There is no usage of the Connections objection in the code.

Comment: Doesn't matter that it's in the code or not. Matters thats it's in the workbook/add-in.

Comment: I added 'ConnCount = ThisWorkbook.Connections.Count' and it does NOT equal zero (was equal to one in the test instance I ran).  I assume this is the reason for the security notice?

Comment: I would be inclined to believe it is so, yes.

Comment: So to my original question, which method(s) result in these types of connections?  I would've thought it was some of those I mentioned in the original post, but when I commented those out, it still displayed the security notice.

Comment: Remove the data connections from the add-in file, they have no business there. If they're generated by code, then they should be generated in `ActiveWorkbook`, not in `ThisWorkbook`. In an add-in project, `ThisWorkbook` refers to the hidden "workbook" that contains the code for the add-in itself. None of the code you've shown does that. It's impossible to tell from your post whether you even *have* code that creates a data connection in `ThisWorkbook`.

Comment: The only usage of `ThisWorkbook` in my code is the debug line I added per your original post.  `ActiveWorkbook` is used everywhere else.

Comment: Again, *it may not be in the code*. Just remove the connections and call it a day.

Comment: And how are connections removed?  I'm not an expert by any means, so simply saying "Just remove the connections and call it a day" provides little help.  From your previous post, it seemed as though you were implying these connections could be the result of using `ThisWorkbook`, and to use `ActiveWorkbook` instead.   If you could provide more detail on how to remove the connections, it'd be appreciated.  Thank you for your help thus far.

Comment: Since I'm not including the entire code here, I realize that it is difficult to troubleshoot.  That being said, the code does open multiple .CSV file in Excel and merges them into a single workbook (along with a variety of data parsing operations).  Wanted to point that out in case it's relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An Excel add-in is just a special kind of `Workbook` project that's loaded as Excel starts. Being a `Workbook` object, it has a `Connections` collection.

I've no idea whether your code needs connections in `ThisWorkbook`, but it appears loading an Excel add-in that has data connections is a security issue - so if you *do* need them, consider researching alternative ways.

To remove them, work in the *immediate pane* (Ctrl+G) - make sure the add-in workbook project is active in the VBA editor.

```
for i = 1 to thisworkbook.connections.count : thisworkbook.connections(1).delete : next
```

That should remove all of them. Save the add-in project, close Excel, re-open, see if you still get the warning.

Comment: Thanks @Mathieu Guindon.  Partially works.  Works when you directly open the .xlam, but when added through the "manage add-ins", the security notice shows up again.

Comment: My previous comment is in error.  The .xlam file lives in a network directory, when I was trying to install it via the "manage add-ins", the browse button was taking me to a local directory that I didn't initially catch.  An old version of the .xlam was in that directory, so I was incorrectly selecting it.  When I pointed it to the network directory location it worked fine with no messages!